# Ambiguous deletion date on deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers

At [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349133/tabcontrol-tab-headings-resize-when-changing-font) on SO, there is a deleted answer (so you'll only be able to see it if you have over 10k).

The answer was posted on December 8, 2008, but the deleted markup reads "deleted by owner Dec 30 at 3:30".  Not that it *really* matters to me when it was deleted (and I can hover over the date to see that it actually was deleted in 2009), but my money was on December 2008 since that's when the answer was posted too.  And if there's one ambiguous date like that, there are certainly many more.

[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/2060/snapstackoverflow5.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/2060/snapstackoverflow5.png)

Comment: If it was deleted in 2008, wouldn't the date have read "Dec 30 '08" just as the last modified date does?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what it would have said.  What makes it somewhat confusing was the fact that it wasn't clear until further inspection whether it was this recent December or the December the answer was posted.  If the answer was posted January 2009, it obviously only could have been one December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the revision history to see more history detail on any post:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/349453/list

Answer (score 2):

I for one don't think this matters - it's only visible to 10K users, who are probably well-versed enough in Stack Overflow to know about hovering over any date on the site, so the confusion really shouldn't last more than a moment or two.

Also, why does it matter when the post was deleted anyway? What difference does it make?

Comment: Yes, the post deletion date isn't terribly important to me; but if the deletion date is not clear on some posts, then perhaps the *edited* date is not clear on other posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a post in January 2010 which tells you that it was deleted in December, what possibilites do you have:

1. Dec 2010 - Hmm, time machine? Anyone?
2. Dec 200... ah, no come on, cannot be!
3. Dec 2008 - Yeah sure, that's what it must be! Bet all my money!

Pro tip: Never visit Las Vegas!